# iOS Subview (UIDatePicker and UIBarButtonItem) does not respond to user input

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fairly new to iOS programming so this might be a really simple mistake. Anyways, I have a subview which I want to appear on top of a "normal" view such that a user can input a date with a UIDatePicker and confirm his choice with a UIBarButtonItem (which will also prompt the subview to disappear) in a UIToolbar. The problem is that the control elements (Picker and Button) dont respond to tapping and other gestures despite being visible on top of the "normal" view. I noticed that a button which is part of the "normal" view responds instead, even though, this button lies beneath the subview and is not visible. Here is the code which generates the subview with its elements:

```
UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 0)];
newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];

UIToolbar * toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 49)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:@selector(dismissCustom:)];
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButtonItem, nil];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
datePicker.hidden = NO;
datePicker.date = [NSDate date];
datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 49, 320, 250);
datePicker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerDateChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[newView addSubview:datePicker];

[newView addSubview:toolbar];
[self.view addSubview:newView];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:newView];

newView.tag = 1;
```

The methods `dismissCustom:` and `pickerDateChanged:` are as follows:

```
-(void)pickerDateChanged:(UIDatePicker *)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

    NSLog(@"Picked the date %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[sender date]]);

    dateButton.titleLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date];
}
```

and

```
-(void)dismissCustom:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
     UIView * newView = [[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:1];
     [newView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what is missing / wrong? Any help is appreciated!
Cheers

Comment: `[[UIView alloc] viewWithTag:]` is certainly wrong. That's not how you use that method.

Comment: The height of newView should not be zero. It needs to be large enough to include the subviews -- try 300.

Comment: Ah many thanks! Settng the height of newView solved the issue! Cheerio!

Answer (score 2):

At least for the button, you need to add a touchUpInside event for the action:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: However, if the button is invisible and you want an action from it you need to make sure it is overlayed on top.